# Javascript | Cambia de color el texto con "document.getElementById("aidCheckboxA").style.color="red";" sólo durante un instante

Tags: javascript

Cambia el color a rojo o verde **sólo durante un instante, pero vuelve al color original** de texto. ¿Por qué no se queda en color verde o rojo?

```js
function correct() {
  var varCheckboxA = document.getElementById("idCheckboxA");
  var varCheckboxB = document.getElementById("idCheckboxB");
  var varCheckboxC = document.getElementById("idCheckboxC");
  var varCheckboxD = document.getElementById("idCheckboxD");
  var avarCheckboxA = document.getElementById("aidCheckboxA");
  var avarCheckboxB = document.getElementById("aidCheckboxB");
  var avarCheckboxC = document.getElementById("aidCheckboxC");
  var avarCheckboxD = document.getElementById("aidCheckboxD");
  var varAnswer = document.getElementById("Answer");

  if (varCheckboxA.checked) {
    if (varAnswer.value == "A") {
      alert("¡Correcto!");
      document.getElementById("aidCheckboxA").style.color = "green";
    } else {
      alert("¡Incorrecto!");
      document.getElementById("aidCheckboxA").style.color = "red";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form class="form-signin p-1">
  <input id="idCheckboxA" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="A" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxA"> A .-{{ tes.a }}</a><br>
  <input id="idCheckboxB" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="B" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxB"> B .-{{ tes.b }}</a><br>
  <input id="idCheckboxC" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="C" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxC"> C .-{{ tes.c }}</a><br>
  <input id="idCheckboxD" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="D" name="fooby[1][]" /><a id="aidCheckboxD"> D .-{{ tes.d }}</a><br>
  <input id="Answer" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" value="{{ tes.get_answer_display }}"><br>

  <button id="correctButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="button" onclick="correct()">Corregir</button>
  <button id="nextButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white; visibility:hidden" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Responder</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado. Faltaba añadir al botón type="button". De esta manera funciona bien y se mantiene. Parece que si no se pone como button, lo toma como submit y refresca la página como cualquier formulario.